# \setlength{\textwidth} unwanted behaviour

Tags: document-classes

The aomart.cls file has a line

```
\setlength{\textwidth}{31pc}
```

that regulates the width of the page. The default is 31pc, and if I increase it (in my own class file which is basically the same as aomart), the pages extend only to the right, making the text look awfully asymmetrical. Is there a way to correct this unwanted behaviour?

Comment: Maybe you can try `geometry`.

Comment: Generally, page width = left margin + textwidth + right margin, so only 3 out of 4 can be set, the remainder being calculated. Evidently your document layout puts the remainder into the right margin. Note that two-sided layouts will flip left/right for odd/even pages. As @Clara noted, the `geometry` package might help, unless you know how to adjust dimensions yourself.

Comment: More precisely, the only way to get the right margin is to subtract everything else from \paperwidth (unless it equals \evensidemargin, which may or may not be the case).

Comment: this is not specific to any class. There is no special behaviour attached to `\setlength`  it just saves the specified value in the supplied  length register. latex uses `\textwidth` as the width of the text block (not the page) so if you make the text wider while placing it at the same position, the right margin is  effectively reduced.  You may prefer to use `geometry` package to set all the related lengths.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle so load my document class but then override it with geometry?

Comment: no use geometry within the class (or set all the lengths notably `\paperwidth` , `\@oddsidemargin` `\@evensidemargin` as well as `\textwidth`